# Buscar datos por mes seleccionado php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla en mysql con tres campos idPago valor mespago. En ella tengo unos datos y quiero hacer una consulta por mespago, que al seleccionar el mes en el datapicker me muestre en una tabla la suma de valor sólo de los que pertenecen al mes seleccionado.
Tengo esto.

```js
//Acá seleccione el mes

<input type="text" id="mespago" name="mespago" class="form-control" 
  <?php $sumapormes = pagoData::pormes("valor");
      echo $sumapormes->sum;?>/>
      
//Esta es la tabla donde quiero mostrar la suma del valor del mes seleccionado

<div class="box-body">
  <?php if (count($reporte)>0): ?>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead id="cabe">
        <th>Suma por mes</th>
      </thead>   
<tr>
<td><?php $apostadoSuma = pagoData::sumar("valor");
      echo $apostadoSuma->suma;?>
</td>                      
</tr>   
</table>
  <?php else: ?>
    <p class="alert alert-warning">No Se Encontraron Datos</p>
  <?php endif; ?>

</div>

//La función que tengo para que me busque por mes

 public static function pormes($valor) {
     $sql="select SUM($valor) AS sum FROM ".self::$tablename." where mespago=$mespago";
  $query = Executor::doit($sql);
  return Model::one($query[0],new pagoData());
 }
```

Pero no me muestra nada al seleccionar algúnmes

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el resultado que te devuelve? Si es tu mensaje de que no se encontraron datos, si la pantalla se queda en blanco o que muestra.

Answer (score 1):

He notado varios errores en tu consulta, el primero es que haces SUM de un valor estático ($valor), eso ya esta raro y lo otro es que tienes otra variable $mespago que no está por ningún lado, no ibas mal, seria algo así:

```
public static function pormes($mesPago) {
        $sql="select SUM(valor) AS sum FROM ".self::$tablename." where mespago=$mesPago";
        $query = Executor::doit($sql);
        return Model::one($query[0],new pagoData());
    }
```

Haciendo de cuenta que todo el resto de interacción con la base de datos este bien creo que debería funcionar.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function pormes($mesPago) {
    $sql="select SUM(valor) AS sum FROM ".self::$tablename." where MONTH(campoFecha)=$mesPago";
    $query = Executor::doit($sql);
    return Model::one($query[0],new pagoData());
}
```

Comment: Desarrolla la respuesta, expica porque es esa la solución. Echale un vistazo a [answer].

Answer (score 0):

el problema podría ser que le estás pasando "valor" al método que ejecuta la query.
También tenes un error en que no estás seteando el valor del input en donde quieres que se muestre.
El input quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php $sumapormes = pagoData::pormes($mes); ?>
<input type="text" id="mespago" name="mespago" class="form-control" 
  value ="<?php echo $sumapormes ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

En MySQL existe una función llamda MONTH() que te devuelve el mes de la fecha que le pases. En este caso que debes filtrar por mes, le aplicas la función a la columna donde se almacen las fechas de pago y te devolvería el mes(por ejemplo MONTH(02-04-2008) te devolvería 4. 
Luego en la query al sumar estar utilizando $value, que es una variable. Debes utilizar el nombre de la columna cuyos valores quieras sumar, que me imagino es value.
Aplicando esto a la función que tenías escrita quedaría así.

Como recomendación importante siempre que trabajes con php y bases de datos: no concatenes variables directamente en las sentencias sql, porque te pueden realizar un sql injection de manera muy sencilla. Siempre parametriza las consultas.

```
public static function pormes($valor) {
    $sql="select SUM(valor) AS sum FROM ".self::$tablename." where 
    ,MONTH(mespago)=$mespago";
    $query = Executor::doit($sql);
    return Model::one($query[0],new pagoData());
}
```